# How to implement CGContext into actual code?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint endlocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
UIImage* thing;
UIImageView* thing2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImageView* thing3=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
switch ([_diagramselect selectedSegmentIndex]) {
    case 0:
        thing = [UIImage imageNamed:@"makeO"];
        [thing2 setFrame:CGRectMake(endlocation.x-72,endlocation.y-172,25,25)];
        [thing2 setImage:thing];
        [_field addSubview:thing2];
        break;
    case 1:
        thing = [UIImage imageNamed:@"missX"];
        [thing2 setFrame:CGRectMake(endlocation.x-72,endlocation.y-172,25,25)];
        [thing2 setImage:thing];
        [_field addSubview:thing2];
        break;
    case 2:
        CGContextRef *context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetStrokeColor(context,black);
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,startlocation.x,startlocation.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,endlocation.x,endlocation.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);





        /*thing = [UIImage imageNamed:@"passArrow"];
        [thing3 setFrame:CGRectMake(startlocation.x-72,startlocation.y-172,endlocation.x-startlocation.x,endlocation.y-startlocation.y)];
        [thing3 setImage:thing];
        [_field addSubview:thing3];
      */

        break;
    case 3:
        thing = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trussArrow"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Case 2 is intended to draw from the initial location of the tap to the end location of the tap. However the following code gives an error of "expected expression" on the line with CGContextRef and as a result the following lines do not recognize context. What is the issue here? Is there a specific view that this code needs to target, and if so how would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: This code will not work, because there is no current context. How To Draw: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html

Answer (score 1):

Try without the pointer reference asterisk:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context,black);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,startlocation.x,startlocation.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,endlocation.x,endlocation.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Furthermore, you may want to look into `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Err, wha?  Did you mean that Apple likes typedef'ing reference types?  I can certainly take the address of a CGContextRef and pass around all the pointers I want.

Comment: No worries!  I'll reword it for you if you promise to get some sleep ;)

Comment: @CodaFi ha!! Yes! Feel free ;) I took the lazy way out and just removed it.